# Origin of "I get that" vs "I get it"

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

In my experience the phrase "I get that" appeared in the last 5-10 years and has picked up a lot.   I see it used often in television and movies. Contrast that with "I get it" which has been around for as long as I can remember.

Both phrases generally mean "I understand", although "I get that" is usually used as an immediate reply to another's statement.

Does anyone know more about this linguistic variant, its origin and usage? (Side note, I kind of can't stand it)

Comment: Your first paragraph is expressing your opinions. Do you have any references to supply ?

Comment: I don't regularly ask this kind of question so I don't know how I'd assemble a reference list for my impressions.  That's basically why I'm asking here, in a community of language experts. An answer below cites 1998 as the earliest reference. I don't know how that user determined that.

Comment: @JoshDiehl - I said that the 1998 usage is the earliest I could find. That doesn’t mean that there may be earlier usages, but as you said, it appears that the expression has become more popular in recent years.

Comment: **I get that** has been around for a very long time. We said it back in the 20th century.  You cannot rely on the internet to tell you about stuff that predated the internet. Not every speech pattern, idiom, or collocation finds its way into a digitized text.

Comment: From 1976. See Page 38, first paragraph and first sentence of the second paragraph. https://www.google.com/books/edition/Current_Economic_Situation_and_Outlook_f/Iu46AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22I+get+that%22&pg=RA2-PA38&printsec=frontcover

Comment: I get it.= I understand the topic you are talking to. I get that.=I get that topic. that=deictic. That means I understand your point. *It* refers to subject matter; *that* refers to a concept, idea or thing. They are interchangeable at times. AND this is **not** anything new in English **at all**.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is reported by the UD in 2015. The use of “that” appears to add more emphasis compared to the pronoun “it”:

[I get that](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20get%20that):

> Statement made by someone who claims to understand a specific problem or issue brought up by others. Conveys active listening and concern.
>   *I know exactly what you're talking about. I get that. I have some ideas on how to fix it.*

The earliest usage I could find dates to the late ‘90s:

From [Sea Swept](https://books.google.it/books?id=7z1J2RUEVPUC&pg=PT87&dq=%22i%20get%20that!%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJr97dtt3YAhVS_qQKHVucAvo4ChDoAQgpMAE#v=onepage&q=%22i%20get%20that!%22&f=false) by 
Nora Roberts - 1998

> “And since I was in the neighborhood, I thought I should come up.” “I want you to go away. Very far away. In fact, I want you to go all the way to hell.” “**I get that**, but before I take the trip, give me five minutes.” “I've already given you what I now consider entirely too much of my time.”